# Access Denied eror in mySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064, access-denied

I am creating new connection in mySQL workbench but i gives me access denied error please tell me whats the mistake?

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the SQL query `SELECT Host, User, Password FROM mysql.user;` (as root) and the password for your `firza` user. How have you added the new user to MySQL? You might need to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` or restart the MySQL server depending on how you have added the user.

Answer (score 0):

first ,you should you can connect the system server,maybe system port of 3306 was close;
second ,you should you login user_name was allow your ip of now,if db is reliease,refuse local to connect ;
third ,you need surr your password is true.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says the user you used is not allowed to connection. There are usually 2 reasons for this problem (not counting typos):

- The user doesn't exist.
- The password is wrong.

Keep in mind that MySQL allows to specify a host from where a user can connect. That means `firza@localhost`, `firza@127.0.0.1` and `firza@%` are 3 different users!